# How can I have Google account bar tabs open in the same window?

Tags: google-chrome, google

I'm taking about the account bar that's at the header of the page, not the Google browser toolbar or the tabs in Chrome itself.

Is there a way to configure the Google account bar to open items in the same window when clicked? i.e. not in a new window but to replace the contents of the current page much like a tab should actually work.

Or perhaps they're not tabs anyway but just a list of links – but I'd like them to be tabs. Any ideas?

*FYI, the account bar has recently had a design update to be black and the Google+ notifications now get listed to the right of it.*

---

**Update**

I've looked at the markup and it appears to be using an anchor for opening the tab bar links.

```
<a target="_blank" class="gbzt" onclick="gbar.logger.il(1,{t:25})"  
   href="https://docs.google.com/?tab=mo&amp;authuser=0">
<span class="gbtb2"></span><span class="gbts">Documents</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You would normally be able to make that sort of change using a Greasemonkey user script, but the Google top bar buttons actually *do* open links on the same tab anyway, so there is something weird going on with your browser.

Comment: @paradroid thanks for the suggestion regarding greasemonkey but from what i can see it's nothing to do with my browser. I work across several machines and i've tried this on ie, ff and chrome where they all open up gmail, google+, picasa, docs, calander ect in new tabs. I've checked the markup and it appears to use an anchor. So I'm wondering how you have yours opening within the same tab.

Comment: Okay, I can see the behaviour that you describe when within `Google Apps` and `Google+`, but not from any of the other Google services, or when clicking *into* `GMail` or `Google+` from them.  These use `https`, and Google has obviously decided to have different behaviour on these web apps.  I think a Greasemonkey user script is your only solution.

Comment: You could possibly write a script that hides the bar altogether and shows a custom made bar in its place. Then just load those links as general href links. Would be nice to customise it so I got links to what I actually used!

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a [Greasemonkey user script which does what you want](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/106265), but it does not currently work from within Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Easy if you use Firefox.

From [ghacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/):

> Users who want to change this behavior need to type in [about:config]
>   in a tab in the Firefox web browser. This should open the Firefox
>   configuration. First time users need to accept a disclaimer. They then
>   need to filter for the term [browser.link.open_newwindow]. The default
>   value of that entry is [3] which opens links that would normally open
>   in a new window in a new tab.
>
> To force Firefox to open links (no matter if they have been designed
>   to open in a new tab or window) in the same tab one would need to
>   change the value to [1](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/) which will open all links that would normally
>   open in a new window in the same tab. Changing the value to [2] would
>   open new windows in a new window (duh).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following setting in Internet Explorer

Tools / Internet Options / TABS - Settings / When a pop-up is encountered